# tinymce images_upload_handler: resize image client-side

Tags: tinymce, image-resizing

i have a minimized upload-handler inside tinymce which creates a dataURI of selected File without creating traffic to the server.

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
   dataURI = "data:" + blobInfo.blob().type + ";base64," + blobInfo.base64(); 
   success(dataURI);
},
```

Now i like to resize blobInfo on clientside to a maximal dimension of 1024px. Something like that:

```
if (blobInfo.width > 1014 || blobinfo.height > 1024) {
   blobInfo = scale_down_to_max_1024px
   NewDataURI = "data:" + blobInfo.blob().type + ";base64," + blobInfo.base64(); 
   success(NewDataURI);
} else {
   dataURI = "data:" + blobInfo.blob().type + ";base64," + blobInfo.base64();
   success(dataURI);
}
```

How can i solve this?